# log loss for multiple classes

Tags: python, scikit-learn, metrics

I am playing with the **log_loss** metric for a classifier.
I tried to use the **log_loss** function in the scikit_learn package, and also I tried to calculate it myself to understand it.
When it applies to binary classes, these two methods give me the same answer. But when I tried to apply it to multiple classes, it gives me different answers, and I am confused.

```
from sklearn.metrics import log_loss
y_true = [0, 1, 2, 2]
y_pred = [[.9, .05,.05], [.8, .1,.1], [.3, .3,.4], [.01, .45, .44]]
print(log_loss(y_true, y_pred,labels=[0,1,2]))


from numpy import log as ln

N = len(y_true)
sum=0

for i in range(0,N):
    sum += ln(y_pred[i][y_true[i]])

log_loss = (1/N)*(-1)*sum
print(log_loss)
```

[log_loss function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XAGZi.png)

The two answers:

```
1.0099640942345076
1.0363042231489643
```

I am sorry for the mistake. It is because some idiot mistake of the probability, and the calculation process has no problem.

0.44 should be 0.54

Comment: you shouldn't redefine the built-in ```sum```

Comment: Thank you for your advice, using the built-in function's name as a variable can be very dangerous. But I change the variable name to "prob_log" and it just gets the same answer. So I assume under this situation it is not the reason causing the problem

Comment: probably due to `normalize=True` in `log_loss`? as it's taking mean loss per sample and not sum of the per-sample losses.

Comment: The idea of the normalization parameter is sth I haven't thought about. But unfortunately it seemed not the reason, if I apply " normalize = False", the result for sklearn log_loss would be 4.0398, and actually, in the calculation, there is a "1/N" multiplier, so it calculate the mean loss.